# Placing items horizontally on Page

Tags: html, css

I am new to html + css and I can't seem to figure out how you place items horizontally despite reading a couple articles. What I am going for is having two lines of text on the right side of my image. Currently I have everything placed vertically.

Html:

````css
#content {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 64px 24px;
}
.section {
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}
.section:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```
````

```html
     <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="section">
                <img src="Images/Logo.png" class="img">
                <h1>Placeholder</h1>
                <h2>Placeholder 2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h6>Projects</h6>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Placeholder</h3>
                        <p> Placeholder </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Placeholder </h3>
                        <p> Placeholder </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I am not sure if I am sharing everything I need too, Here's the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ArnavMotwani/ARNV) with all the code if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`display: flex;` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
/* ↓ new styling ↓ */

.section-horizontal {
  display: flex;
}

.description {
  margin-left: 32px;
}

/* your styling */

#content {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 64px 24px;
}

.section {
  padding-bottom: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.section:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="section section-horizontal"> <!-- class for flexbox -->
    <img src="Images/Logo.png" class="img">
    <div class="description"> <!-- add this block to align headings vertically -->
      <h1>Placeholder</h1>
      <h2>Placeholder 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <h6>Projects</h6>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Placeholder</h3>
        <p> Placeholder </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Placeholder </h3>
        <p> Placeholder </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to get in touch with the flex property. It will make things alot more simple :)

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="section">
            <img src="Images/Logo.png" class="img">
            <div class="flex">
               <h1>Placeholder</h1>
               <h2>Placeholder 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.flex {
   display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with flexbox like this

```css
    #content {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 64px 24px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.section {
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}
.section:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="section">
            <img src="Images/Logo.png" class="img">
            <h1>Placeholder</h1>
            <h2>Placeholder 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <h6>Projects</h6>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>Placeholder</h3>
                    <p> Placeholder </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>Placeholder </h3>
                    <p> Placeholder </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```